# Pandas to_csv() inserting values in wrong order

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am geocoding a simple CSV file and output the results into another CSV file. When inspecting the file using PDB, the order seems correct - the outputted data, however, is in the wrong order. What is the reason for this? I have not been able to find an option for df.to_csv() to ensure correct column order.

```python
import pandas
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
nom = Nominatim(user_agent="syria_test")

csv_file_in = '../geometry/villages.csv'
csv_file_out = '../geometry/villages_geocoded.csv'

villages = pandas.read_csv(csv_file_in)

total = 0
success = 0

for index, row in villages.iterrows():
  try:
    location = nom.geocode(row['name'], country_codes='sy')
    villages.at[index, 'lat'] = location.latitude
    villages.at[index, 'lng'] = location.longitude
    success += 1
  except:
    pass

  total += 1

villages.to_csv(csv_file_out, index_label='index')

print(f'Completed {success}/{total} ({((success / total) * 100):.2f}%) locations.')
```

villages.csv:

```
id,name,lat,lng
1,الرهجان,,
2,مسكنة,,
3,كبش غربي,,
4,السخنة,,
5,الشدادي,,
6,بستا سويس,,
```

villages_geocoded.csv:

```
index,id,name,lat,lng
0,1,الرهجان,,
1,2,مسكنة,35.960035,38.0412782
2,3,كبش غربي,36.1315275,38.7845704
3,4,السخنة,34.8826632,38.8714412
4,5,الشدادي,36.0615047,40.7342072
5,6,بستا سويس,,
```

This is how it looks in pdb:
[Image from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQkKT.png)

Comment: Why do you need it to maintain order?

Comment: The coordinate fields are inserted into the name field and the name is pushed to the end - almost like it is reversing order. I need to maintain order for the csv file to remain consistent